# What are the OpenSSL API calls to get transmitted cert status information after the (last) call to SSL_connect()?

Tags: openssl

Specifically, I would like to determine, by querying the SSL object, which of the following cases apply:

- No outgoing cert was provisioned.
- Cert was provisioned but the server never requested it.
- Handshake terminated right after send of cert was acked.
- Handshake continued after send of cert was acked.

Comment: This is a pure coding question, i.e. off-topic here. Apart from that I doubt that you get these information directly from the SSL object, at least not through some documented API. You can check [the info callback](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_set_info_callback.html) though which allows you to track at which stage of the SSL handshake the object currently is and thus you can see where it breaks.

Comment: Is there somewhere it would be on-topic?

Comment: stackoverflow.com is about such kind of code focused question although it is usually expected that you show own efforts first. But again, try the info callback.

Comment: There is no point in trying the info callback as the documentation indicates it returns different information than what I am trying to obtain.